# M8 unlocked when picked up.

Tags: htc

I have an HTC m8. The other day I sat it flat on my desk. Every time I would pick it up, the screen would automatically unlock and light up. My thoughts were that's neat how have I never noticed this before, it knows when I pick up the phone. Today I cant get it to do it. I've tried all different positions on flat surfaces and it simply will not wake up upon being picked up. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It could be those gestures .Try enabling the gestures on settings>Display & Gestures >Motion launch gesture >Enable it.